# How to create zip without subfolders in Python?

Tags: python, linux, zip, compression

I've got some files in `/tmp/1234/` and I'm creating a zip using Python:

```
def create_local_zip_file(zipjob_number, folder_path):
    zip_file_path = os.path.join('/tmp/', f'{zipjob_number}.zip')
    with ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'w') as zip_obj:
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, "*")):
            zip_obj.write(filename)
    return zip_file_path
```

This creates a zip, but when I unzip the created zip file I get a folder called `tmp` which in turn contains a folder called `1234` which then contains the files.

How can I make sure the unzip creates a folder called `1234` containing the files directly?

Comment: use the arcname parameter -- zip_obj.write(filename, arcname="whatever")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like each of your filenames includes the folder, which is why they're being written in to a directory within the zipfile.

You can use the "arcname" parameter to give the files a different name within the archive

I can see a way to do this with string splitting, however can I suggest using pathlib instead. Something like:

```
from pathlib import Path

...
for file in Path(folder_path).glob("*"):
    zip_obj.write(file, arcname=file.name)
...
```